# How to use literal "." in Apache VirtualDocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm struggling with `VirtualDocumentRoot` in Apache 2.4 - I want to have a value that changes the TLD from the requested domain to a different one to map to the document root on disk:

```
User request: https://one.example.net
Doc root: /var/www/one.example.com
```

I have tried various options, but Apache always complains about the syntax. My best guess was `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-2+%.com`. In pseudo-code that should read `/var/www/, "the penultimate and all preceding parts of the domain", escape character, period, "com"`

I'd guess that my mistake is in the escape character. It's either wrong, or there simply isn't one and `%%` to give a literal % is a special case.

Can anyone suggest a working solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frustratingly I have found my answer in the official docs - I clearly wasn't reading carefully enough... The [final example](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) says:

`If you want to include the . character in a VirtualDocumentRoot directive, but it clashes with a % directive, you can work around the problem in the following way: VirtualDocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/vhosts/%2.0.%3.0"`

So for my case I need to use `VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-2+.0.com`.
My interpretation is that using the `.0` sub-string variable "closes" the variable allowing the use of a literal `.`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-2+\.com
```

Comment: I have now, thanks! It feels like progress, but doesn't work unfortunately. There's no syntax error, but a 404 - it must not get parsed in the way we think it should.

I realise an extra trouble is I don't know how to debug the interpretation of VirtualDocumentRoot - afaik you can't add it to access.log for example